# Python, numpy, string decomposition (string from Abaqus AFXComTableKeyword.getValues())

Tags: python, string, numpy

From the `getValues()`method the `AFXComTableKeyword` class returns a string like:

```
test = "('mat_huehne_2008', '0.125', '24.0'),('', '', '-24.0'),('', '', '41.0')"+\
       ",('', '', '-41.0'),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('','', ''),"+\
       "('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),"+\
       "('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),"+\
       "('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),"+\
       "('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),"+\
       "('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),"+\
       "('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),('', '', ''),"+\
       "('', '', ''),('', '', '')"
```

At the end we need a `numpy.array` of `shape=(40,3)`, that for this case would look like:

```
 test = [['mat_huehne_2008', '0.125',  '24.0'],
         [               '',      '', '-24.0'],
         ... and so on ... ]
```

Does anyone know a shortcut to do that in Python / Numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `ast` to eval the string into tuples.  then it's easy:

```
>>> import ast
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(ast.literal_eval(test))
array([['mat_huehne_2008', '0.125', '24.0'],
       ['', '', '-24.0'],
       ['', '', '41.0'],
       ['', '', '-41.0'],
       ...
```

Comment: @SaulloCastro -- Yes, `eval` will also work, but is vulnerable to all sorts of attacks.